# Caption YouTube videos that are not mine

Tags: youtube

I need to caption YouTube videos that are not mine (I currently link to them).  I don't believe I can edit and add captions when I am not the original owner.  However, can I download a video and then upload it under my account?  Then I ought to be able to caption it, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to download it.  You can use a free service called [Amara](http://amara.org/en/) (formerly called Universal Subtitles) to "caption in the cloud," so to speak.  Once you've completed typing the captions and syncing them to the video (again, in the cloud with their browser based interface) it will generate an embed code from Amara that you can put in the HTML of your preferred page.  It also does an interactive transcript.  Very nifty.

Comment: Welcome to the Web Applications Stack Exchange site. Please take the [tour](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) as it will help you to _learn the ropes_.